# Problem with understanding contravariant component transform

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, vector-fields, covariance

I am reading Susskinds book General Relativity: The theoretical minimum and I got a bit stuck on the transformation rule of contravariant components. The book defines the components of a vector $(V^{’})^m=\frac{\partial Y^m}{\partial X^p}V^p$ where the primed system corresponds to changing from coordinates X to Y. My question is this: a contravariant vector is supposed to transform *contrary* to be base, but if I let the new basis Y be defined as $Y^m=2 X^m$ that is every basis vector is twice as long, however I do the calculation I find that my components *also* become twice as large according to the rule above. And from my understanding it is supposed to be the opposite. Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tangent vector $\dot\lambda_p =(d\lambda /dt)_p $ to a curve parameterised by $t$ at a point $p$ on it is the map from the set of real functions $f$ defined in neighbourhood of $p$ to $\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$ \dot\lambda_p :f \mapsto \left[ d(f\circ  \lambda)/dt\right]_p $$
Given a chart $\phi$ with coordinates $x^i$, the components of $\dot\lambda_p$ w.r.t. chart are $$\dot{ [ x^i \circ \lambda]_p} = \left[\frac{d}{dt}x^i(\lambda(t))\right]_p $$
Denote $\dot\lambda_k(0) =\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\right)_p$ and from this any tangent vector $X_p$ (p is denoting point) as
$$X_p f=\dot{(f\circ \lambda)}(0)=\dot{[f\circ\phi^{-1} \circ \phi \circ \lambda]}
=\sum_k\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\right) \left (f\circ\phi^{-1}\right)\dot{\left( x^k \circ \lambda \right)}(0)=\sum_k\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\right)_p f \left(X_p x^k\right)$$

So $$X_p = \sum_k \left(X_p x^k\right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\right)_p$$
The $X_p x^k$ are just the components of $X_p$.
Now on using Einstein's summation convention

A vector $X_p=X^k \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\right)_p$

Now if we change the coordinates by a transformation $x^i \mapsto y^i(x^m)$

And consider $$X_p f = X^k \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}\right)_p = X^k \left(\frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^k}\right) \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^m}\right)_p = X'^m \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^m}\right)_p $$

Where $X'^m = X^k \left(\frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^k}\right)$

So what's written in your book is correct.

**Edit**

Now if you consider $y^i =2x^i$ you get $$X'^m = X^k \left(\frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^k}\right)=2 X^m$$
But basis $$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^m}\right)_p= \left(\frac{\partial f}{2\partial x^m}\right)_p $$
Which makes $$X_p=X'^m \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^m}\right)_p=2X^k \left(\frac{\partial f}{2\partial x^k}\right)_p=X^k \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}\right)_p $$
Which is invariant and your basis actually halves with that coordinate transformation.

Comment: I kind of lied to you in last part, because am lazy. But you sure can get idea.

Comment: In the last part before edit I took it as normal differential operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is not the case. It is an operator over some manifold.

Comment: Aah I see! So I agree that the formula is correct. But when we write $X^{’m} = 2 X^m$ doesn’t that imply that my components in X’ is now double those in X? But since the basis is twice as long I expected components to be half.

Comment: You see when components are doubled it's natural for the basis to be halved to keep the vector invariant.

Comment: Your choice of coordinate transformation actually halves the basis.

Comment: Oooh! What a silly mistake! Thats why all calculation were wrong. Thank you so much for you explanation!

Comment: Just so I am clear then, how would you write the change of basis to double the basis? Wouldn’t it be written $\hat{y}_i=2 \hat{x}_i$?

Comment: That's an interesting thing, for that you need to see the dual vectors and imagine your dual vectors as some kind of lines ( contour maps) , just to be clear try to see different kind of maps (the world map and terrain maps of different locations) and see how things work there and then try to relate it with the coordinate system you are using.

Comment: By, the way to double the basis you need to spread the grid lines of a graph,  , double the distance between them,